# How to delete AWSServiceRoleForSupport in AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm getting this error below,

> **Role deletion failed**
>
> AWS Support Service Linked Role (SLR) cannot be deleted since it is necessary for providing administrative, operational and technical support for your AWS account.

Comment: The most annoying thing is that once this error message appears, it doesn't ever seem to go away. It's just there, forever, reminding you that 18 months ago you accidentally tried to delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The role can't be deleted. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssupport/latest/user/using-service-linked-roles-sup.html):

> The AWSServiceRoleForSupport role is necessary for AWS Support to provide administrative, operational, and technical support for your account. As a result, this role **can't be deleted** through the IAM console, API, or CLI.

Comment: The role is important for technical support hence it cant be!!!

Answer (score 2):

As @marcin said you cant, but i would like to mention The reasons `why` it cannot be deleted :-

- To provide world-class customer service and technical support in
  order to gather information about your AWS resources through API
  calls.
- AWS Support uses this service-linked role in various ways like
  **Billing, administrative,Processing of service attributes, Maintaining the operational health of your account and its
  resources**.
- **To provide these services, the role's predefined permissions give AWS Support access to resource metadata, not customer data. Only AWS
  Support tools can assume this role, which exists within your AWS
  account.**
- > You can use IAM to edit the description for the AWSServiceRoleForSupport service-linked role. **However The
  > AWSServiceRoleForSupport role is necessary for AWS Support to provide
  > administrative, operational, and technical support for your account.
  > As a result, this role can't be deleted through the IAM console, API,
  > or CLI. This protects your AWS account, because you can't
  > inadvertently remove necessary permissions for administering support
  > services.**